# Count values in one dataframe that are less than all the values in another

Tags: python, time-limit-exceeded, pandas

I currently have 2 dataframes, **A and B**. These dataframes are generated in runtime, and **increase in size** according to parameters in the program execution.

I need to evaluate how many times a value in dataframe A is lesser than all the values in dataframe B.

For example:

```
Dataframe A
+-----+-------+
| id  | value |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | 0.23  |
|   2 | 1.2   |
+-----+-------+
Dataframe B
+-----+-------+
| id  | value |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | 0.22  |
|   2 | 1.25  |
|   3 | 0.3   |
|   4 | 0.5   |
|   5 | 0.9   |
|   6 | 0.0   |
+-----+-------+
```

I need to check how many values greater than 0.23 (for example) are in dataframe B. in this case 4 of the 6.

My first try with this was using this code. In this case, `bio_dataframe` is dataframe A, an `random_seq_df` is dataframe B.

```py
for bio_row in bio_dataframe.itertuples():
    total = 0
    for ran_row in random_seq_df.itertuples():
        if bio_row[2] < ran_row[2]:
            total += 1
```

As you can see, i use `itertuples` for fast iteration of the rows of the dataframes.
This approach works "well" for dataframes below 25000 rows, but beyond that it starts to get painfully slow.

So my next approach was this.

> `final_res` is a column in the dataframe.

```py
for bio_row in bio_dataframe.itertuples():
    a = bio_row[2]
    total = random_dataframe.eval('final_res > @a')
```

It works excellent until 100000 rows, beyond that the story repeats.

I'm hitting a wall here and I've run out of ideas to test. Is there any way to improve the code? Am I missing something, or some snippet to make it faster?

Comment: Have you tried `(bio_dataframe < random_dataframe.min()).sum()`? Also, the Indentation in your first code block is off.

Comment: You code also seems to be doing something different from your description. It seems to be comparing two columns, one row at a time. Your description talks about comparing to the minimum of all rows in the second column.

Comment: @Graipher, i added a more detailed example, for me is explained correctly, but English is not my first language.

Comment: How often is Dataframe A1 changed?  Is it constant for the life of the program or constantly changing?  Same thing for the values in Dataframe B.  This would be easier to review with more code.

Comment: If you'r asking wondering if the dataframes change size in between the analysis, they don't. I only put that to demonstrate that the size is not constant. @mdfst13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a good idea to sort the columns you wish to compare first. That way you can iterate over both lists a single time. The idea is to use the index to keep track of how many items are larger than the values in your first list. A relatively untested function is:

```python
import pandas as pd
import time

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['a'] = [0.23, 1.2]
df2['a'] = [0.22, 1.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.0] * 1000 # Add some extra work


def sol(da, db):
    # Sort your columns 
    x = sorted(da)
    y = sorted(db)

    t = []  # The results
    yi = iter(y)  # Use of an iterator to move over y
    yindex = 0
    y_item = next(yi)

    for val in x:
        # Search through y to find the index of an item bigger than val
        while y_item <= val:
            if yindex == len(y) - 1:
                t.append(0)
                return t
            y_item = next(yi)
            yindex += 1
        # Use the length of y and the index to find the number of item
        # larger than the current val
        t.append(len(y) - yindex)  
    return t

t0 = time.time()
print sol(df1['a'], df2['a'])
print time.time() - t0

>>> [4000, 1000]
0.00200009346008
```

The problem with your initial solution is that you iterate over your second list for every value in your first list giving you an n^2 run time. This can be seen if you increase the length of the first list a bit. Ive modified your function a little to demonstrate:

```python
def sol0(df1, df2):
    b = df2['a']
    for bio_row in df1.itertuples():
        a = float(bio_row[1])
        total = pd.eval('b > a')
        df1.set_value(bio_row[0], 'sim_p_val', total.sum())
    return df1
```

Testing with the following shows how the n^2 approach can get slow with longer lists, using the sorted list approach is ~750x quicker in this example:

```python
df1['a'] = [0.23, 1.2] * 1000
df2['a'] = [0.22, 1.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.0] * 1000

t0 = time.time()
res = sol(df1['a'], df2['a'])
print time.time() - t0

df1['sim_p_val'] = [0]*len(df1)
t0 = time.time()
df1 = sol0(df1, df2)
print time.time() - t0

# Verify the result is the same
print res == sorted(list(df1['sim_p_val']), reverse=True)



>>>0.0024299621582
1.78539991379
True
```

Comment: Seems like a get your point on the code, let me test it with my data and ill post the results! thanks for the input!

Comment: Well, indeed it's a lot more faster than my solution. Im accepting this as the best solution! 
Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a bit of code that can be used to speed up comparison and calculations in Pandas, `pandas.eval`:

```
b = random_dataframe['final_res']
for bio_row in bio_dataframe.itertuples():
    a = float(bio_row[2])
    total = pd.eval('b > a')
    bio_dataframe.set_value(bio_row[0], 'sim_p_val', (total.sum() / len(b.index)))
```

First you get the column of the dataframe to analyze (gets saved as a pandas series):

```
b = random_dataframe['final_res']
```

Later, the value to compare to the whole column:

```
a = float(bio_row[2])
```

At least in my case, I had to specify the type of data.

To finally analyze both:

```
total = pd.eval('b > a')
```

It gets a substantial boost in speed and the output is correct, but it seems that I can't get rid of the iteration. Anyway, it suits for me at least for the moment!